# Filter list based on nested list with lambda

Tags: java, android, list, lambda, nested

I have a Group object that looks like this

```
public class Group { 
    private String mName;
    private List<Item> mItems;
}
```

and an Item object that looks like this

```
public class Item {
    private String mNumber;
}
```

Now let's say I have a first list like `List<Group> { ["Group1", {Item1, Item2, Item3}] }` and a second one like `List<Group> { ["Group1", {Item2}] }`.
I would like to remove Item2 from the first list with lambda.

What I have so far is the following but I'm stuck in the middle.

```
firstList.stream()
.flatMap(group -> group.getItemList().stream())
.filter(item -> (
        // here I'm stuck. I think i need a stream of the second list or something?
        ))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The result should look like `List<Group> {["Group1", {Item1, Item3}]}`

Comment: Do you wish to mutate the existing `List` (`firstList`) or create a new output `List`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pramod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2249249/pramod) pointed me to the right direction to solve my problem :)
The solution is:

```
firstList.stream()
.filter(secondList::contains) // added this later because I only need groups wich are in both lists
.map(group -> {
    List<Item> items = group.getItemList().stream()
            .filter(item -> !(secondList.stream().flatMap(group2 -> group2.getItemList().stream())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                    .contains(item))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    group.setItemList(items);
    return group;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, If you can do it through flatMap approach.
Here is the slightly different approach.

Assuming you have overridden `equals` and `hashcode` methods for `Item` class and Group List will contain unique items. Also, I am assuming that `Group` `mName` attribute can be used to identify relation between group in two group list

```
    List<Group> groupList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Group> groupList2 = new ArrayList<>();

    Group group1 = new Group();
    group1.setMName("group1");
    group1.setMItems(Lists.newArrayList(new Item("item1"),new Item("item2"), new Item("item3")));
    groupList1.add(group1);

    Group group2 = new Group();
    group2.setMName("group1");
    group2.setMItems(Lists.newArrayList(new Item("item2")));
    groupList2.add(group2);

    Map<String, Group> group2Map = groupList2.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(group -> group.getMName(), Function.identity()));

    List<Group> finalGroupList = groupList1.stream().filter(group -> group2Map.get(group.getMName()) != null)
            .map(group -> {
                Group grp = group2Map.get(group.getMName());
                List<Item> items = group.getMItems().stream().filter(item -> !grp.getMItems().contains(item)).collect(Collectors.toList());
                group.setMItems(items);
                return group;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
//finalGroupList  will be similar to <Group> {["Group1", {Item1, Item3}]}
```

Comment: thank you! although your exact code didn't work for me you pointed me in the right direction to solve my problem. upvoted

Answer (score 0):

The lastlist not contains

```
firstList.stream()
.flatMap(group -> group.getItemList().stream())
.filter(item -> (!lastList.countains(item)))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but !lastList.contains(item) doesnt work because lastList is of type List<Group> and item is of type Item

Comment: so, !lastList.Items.countains(item)??

Comment: If you just remove the duplication, you can try to sort out the item list first

Answer (score 0):

This would give you the updated mItems, assuming you dont want to mutate the existing..

```
var mItems = first.stream()
        .flatMap(group -> group.getMItems().stream())
        .filter(item -> !(second.stream().anyMatch(g -> g.getMItems().contains(item))))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`result: [Item(mNumber=Item1), Item(mNumber=Item3)`